# Converting ASCII numerical character to actual character

Tags: c++, binary, hex, ascii

I'm learning about **ASCII**, and how it encodes characters. To my understanding (although I may be wrong because I'm still learning), it is that **ASCII** encodes numbers as characters. For example, something like this:

**0011 0000 = 30 = '0'** (this being an encoded character)

**0000 0000 =  0 = 0** (while this being an actual number)

represents two different types of encoding of zero.

## Question

Is there any way to display the true number for an **ASCII** *char* data type?

I attempted the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    char e = '0';

    std::cout << e << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(e) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

I know this code is not close to the result I am trying to accomplish; however, it was all I could think of. I need a better understanding of how this *conversion* can be accomplished through C++ syntax.

Also, please excuse me of any *misleading* information or title. I am still learning the "ropes" of programming.

Comment: "ASCII encodes numbers as characters" - it's the other way around... ASCII encodes characters as numbers.  (You wouldn't "encode" numbers into ASCII because in general you'd have garbage text with control characters mixed in, which is of no use to anybody, but we have to have some encoding for text to pass it around inside computers.)  You were so close!

Comment: All character encodings, and there are many of them, not just ASCII, use numbers to represent characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast the `char` to an `int`.

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(e);
```

The `char` actually already is an integer, it's just that the overload of `operator<<` taking a `char` displays it as a character.  By using the cast to change the type to `int`, we are causing a different overload of the operator to be called, one which is written to display as an integer.

Comment: Excellent explanation, but does doing this cause the Char variable 'e' to become an int data type for the rest of the program?

Comment: @Jake2k13: No. This operation has no effect on the `e` variable.  It creates a new, temporary, unnamed `int` variable with the same value.

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding you want the actual values stored in memory that is for '0'=0x30=48. In memory `char` data type is also stored as integer but in 8 bit format. Because of this if you type cast the variable with int then you will get the stored value in integer format not in Ascii char.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    char e = '0';

    std::cout << (int)e << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(e) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1.  Just by way of further explanation for the OP and other readers, `static_cast<int>(e)` is a new C++-only way to request the conversion that would generate a compiler error if "e" wasn't of a sensible type for this conversion, while `(int)e` was carried over from the C language, does the same thing, is nicely concise but a little less safe.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    char e = '0';

    std::cout << e - '\0' << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(e) << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Try it with `char e` equal any character and it will print the actual value of the character. Thanks to `chris` for suggesting another way of doing this; which is by casting the character to `int`.

```
std::cout << static_cast<int>(e) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I'd rather see a cast than a subtraction of zero tbh.

Comment: @chris, isn't the "zero" in this case a "null character"?

Comment: Yes, but it's less clear than `static_cast<int>(e)` in my opinion. If shorter was always better, we'd end up with APL or Perl or something everywhere.

Comment: @Jake2k13: It is. But there is a peculiar set of rules in the standard (often referred to as integer promotion), one of the effects of which is that, essentially, if you perform math between two operands, both of which are integer types smaller than `int`, they are promoted to `int`, and the result of the operation is an `int`.